# How to get template function from so/dll?

Tags: function, templates, dll, shared-libraries, d

How to get template function from so/dll?
I tried:

```
Library libdll;
T abc(T)();
static this()
{
    libdll = Library("libs/libdll.so");
    abc = cast(typeof(abc)) libdll.loadSymbol!(typeof(abc))("dll.abc");
    //abc();
}
```

But then the type of `abc` is determined as `void`.
I get error in the compilation:

```
Error: expression `cast(void)dlsym(this.handle, toStringz(cast(const(char)[])m))` is `void` and has no value
```

`m` - is the mangled name of `dll.abc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates in D are a compile-time-only construct, and don't exist in sos/dlls. Specific instances end up in the so, but only those that are used there. In other words, if you have this code in the so/dll:

```
module dll;

T abc(T)() {
    T result = void;
    return result;
}

void use() {
    auto var = abc!int();
}
```

You should be able to get `dll.abc!int.abc` (mangled name `_D3dll__T3abcTiZQhFNaNbNiNfZi`) from the so/dll.

If you want to call `abc` with some other type, like `abc!string`, you're out of luck - the code just doesn't exist.

That covers the feasibility. If you only want a specific instance you know has been instantiated, there's another issue at work here, which is the use of `typeof(abc)`. Again, `abc` is a compile-time thing, and doesn't have a type. The compiler, confusingly, returns `void` for `typeof(abc)`, giving you the error message `` is `void` and has no value ``.

`abc!int` is a function, and does have a type (`pure nothrow @nogc @safe int()`), so using that should work. As hinted at above, the name would be `dll.abc!int.abc` (it's an [eponymous template](https://dlang.org/spec/template.html#implicit_template_properties), hence the repeated name).

TL;DR: If you want a specific instance of the template, and that  has been instantiated in the so/dll, this code should work (but has not been tested):

```
Library libdll;
T abc(T)();
static this()
{
    libdll = Library("libs/libdll.so");
    abc = cast(typeof(abc!int)) libdll.loadSymbol!(typeof(abc!int))("dll.abc!int.abc");
    abc();
}
```

Comment: I have made a concrete example using your answer to show how to use this: https://wfr.moe/c6m1Hn/dll-sample.d

Comment: Very thanks. Today I've made functions and templates friends in my code but I faced which you've explained in beginning. `T` problem. Different types don't exist if I will not explicitly address a template in the DLL source code. Thank you.